# Inside the unit square lie several circles the sum of whose circumferences is equal to 10. Prove that there

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, contest-math

[image]Inside the unit square lie several circles the sum of whose circumferences is equal to
$10$. Prove that there exist infinitely many lines each of which intersects at least four of
the circles
This question is from a famous book however the solution given is not clear.

We place the unit square in standard position. The “boxes” are the vertical lines crossing
the square, while the “objects” are the horizontal diameters of the circles (Figure $56$). Both
the boxes and the objects come in an infinite number, but what we use for counting is length
on the horizontal. The sum of the diameters is
$\frac{10}{π} = 3 × 1 + ε, ε > 0$.

Consequently, there is a segment on the lower side of the square covered by at least four
diameters. Any vertical line passing through this segment intersects the four corresponding
circles.
Why is ε used and should $\frac{10}{π} = 2(r_1 +r _2 + r_3 +....r_n)$

Comment: $\epsilon>0$ is used because we need the sum of the diameters to be strictly greater than $3$, so as to guarantee an infinite number of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is just saying that $2(r_1+ \dots + r_n)$ is larger than $3$ in a weird way, so he is just saying that the sum of the diameters is larger than $3$ but in a kind of weird way.

Let $f(x)$ be the number of circles that intersect the vertical line through $(x,0)$.

The integral from $0$ to $1$ of $f(x)$ is equal to the sum of the diameters of the circles, since this value is larger than $3$ there must be $x$ such that $f(x)>3$, and since $f$ is integer valued we have $f(x)\geq 4$. So this is the line we need.

Incidentally you can take exactly $4$ circles with sum of circunference equal to $10$, so $4$ is the minimum.

Comment: Perfectly explained. Can you please also let me know if there is any specific reason why 10/π = 3×1+ε and not only  3+ε?

Comment: the only thing that I can think of that the user is trying to explain it as $a = dq+r$, you know, like when you divide something, where you get a quotient and a remainder? So he may be saying, we divide $(10/\pi)$ by $3$ and we get $1$ as a quotient and $\epsilon$ as a remiander. Although I am not completely sure

Comment: Maybe he is dividing by $1$ in order to calculate the floor of the number, and he is getting $3$ as the quotient and $\epsilon$ as the remainder.

Comment: Oh! Could be. Anyway. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure. ${}{}$